# What is the precise definition of a "read" in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

In [the docs](https://www.mongodb.com/pricing) it says *"$0.10/million reads"*.

I have a collection with a 1 million documents. I was testing some intensive queries just for one day by myself and my account accumulated a charge of $26.

Not sure how I got there.

So I need to know the precise definition of a "read". Is it each time a document is accessed from disk?

Comment: That's Atlas (the hosted service) specifically, not MongoDB generally. It says **from** $0.10, and there's more information on the pricing _on the page you've linked to_. Regurgitating what that (currently) says has no durable value to SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the time of writing https://www.mongodb.com/pricing reads:

| Item | Description | Pricing |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Read Processing Unit (RPU) | Number of read operations* to the database ** Sum of documents read divided by 4KB and index bytes read divided by 256 bytes* | $0.10 / million for the first 50 million per day* |

If I get it, 1 read is fetching up to 4Kb of a document or up to 256b of index, e.g. querying whole million of documents in the first stage of an aggregation pipeline costs $0.1 if your documents are about 4Kb each.

I would strongly advise to talk to Atlas support tho. Don't rely on my understanding of what's written there.